# Looking for (free) Java code editor (IDE) for Windows

Tags: java, windows, ide

Not to be open-ended I will list my requirements.

- Must have **native UI** (or at least .net the backend can be Java I don't care)
- Must work with **Ant** (basic functionality is enough, as long as it shows Ant's output and double-clicking on *[javac] errors* inside ant outputs *jumps to the referenced line*)
- Must have **code completion** (including my source code and third party `.jar`s, no just JFC classes)

Extras (function which would help a lot):

- Showing my classes and methods in a treeview
- Alert for undefined symbols before compiling
- Unicode support
- Some form of integration with javadoc style documentation (reading JFC and other on-line documentation which was made by javadoc)

I think these are pretty down-to earth requirements.

Comment: Why is this supposed to be closed as subjective? I don't think a subjective answer is possible here. The requirements are pretty clear. Upvoted again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use Eclipse? Then you could've listed about 200 more extras in your requirements...

Comment: Thanks, but Eclipse also uses Java-based IDE AFAIK. I do a lot of coding, so I long for the responsiveness of a native app. Also matters if things are where I'm looking for them. :)

Comment: It's SWT, i.e. a Java-based native GUI. Check it out here: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/

Comment: @vbence, For almost all IDEs, the performance is slowed down by disk access to get cached information.  The speed of screen update shouldn't be an issue for any PC sold in the last 15 years.

Comment: I will give Eclipse a try. Although I'm a little afraid of an IDE with a 100 Megs download :)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse?!   http://www.eclipse.org

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) is the best free Java IDE that I have used.

Answer (score 1):

All the most popular IDEs should do what you have listed and a lot more. I prefer IntelliJ CE which is more productive for me. Eclipse and Netbeans are also excellent free IDEs.

In terms of screen update, I use a 2100x1600 window, sometimes locally and sometimes via VNC on our LAN and screen update speed is not an issue.  Sometimes I have projects with a total of over 10,000 classes open. ;)

---

Update: I now use a 4K screen with over 30K classes in project with IntelliJ.

Comment: These days I'm using IntelliJ-based IDEs (FDT, Android Studio) next to NetBeans and they really feel much more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Visual J++ was an IDE from Microsoft that was shipped with Visual Studio until it was discontinued a few years ago. You might be able to get your hands on it and it should be able to follow your requirements to a certain point, but it is a discontinued product. (I don't think you mentioned it has be free.)
There has been Borland's JBuilder and possibly several other IDE's but I do concur with previous posters that Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ will most likely do the job very well.
There's also Oracle's JDeveloper but since it's been rewritten I think it's also written in Java.

The only requirement that will be hard to meet is 'must have native UI'.

> I long for the responsiveness of a native app

I doubt that you would settle for an online IDE then :-)

Googling for 'native java IDE' brings up (among others) [Optistic](http://optistic.com). Might be worth a visit.

Lots of choices but not so many 'native UI' ones. Good luck making the right choice :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check it out. Although I currently use an other discontinued product. That's what I try to replace with a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

That would be either Netbeans or Eclipse if you are looking for something featurefull with nice graphical stuff, of vim or emacs if you are looking for something slimmer (with a much steeper learning curve)

Comment: I guess, Netbeans somewhat fails on the "Native UI" requirement